# What is the request limit number in the blockchain.info API?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I'm planning to use https://www.blockchain.com/api, precisely single block https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_api for testing purposes on my script.

I noticed there this line on the the API site 'Request Limits: To bypass the request limiter, please request an API key', the registration for an API key required me to have a website or app but I don't have any.

I'm planning to use their API to run a script for a few days to test.

So I'm wondering: does anyone know what is the current request limit for their API? I see no mention about the request number on the website or document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be 1 request every 10 seconds:

https://www.blockchain.com/api/q

Comment: is this correct? i tried to call from postman constantly and it seems normal, not looking like 1 request every 10 seconds